# Имеет ли смысл выносить общие части путей в DataContext на уровень выше?

Tags: wpf

Предположим, у меня есть блок, все байндинги в котором привязаны к параметрам одного объекта. Имеет ли смысл (в плане производительности) выносить его на верхний уровень в `DataContext` или значительной разницы не будет?

Например, с `DataContext`:

```
<StackPanel mui:Switch.When="{x:Static t:ServerStatus.Error}" DataContext="{Binding Entry}">
    <!-- server's name -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />

    <!-- ip, ping -->
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:{1}">
                <Binding Path="Ip" Mode="OneWay" />
                <Binding Path="PortHttp" Mode="OneWay" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

    <mui:BbCodeBlock BbCode="{Binding ErrorsString}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Content="{x:Static c:ControlsStrings.Common_TryAgain}" />
</StackPanel>
```

И без:

```
<StackPanel mui:Switch.When="{x:Static t:ServerStatus.Error}">
    <!-- server's name -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Entry.DisplayName}" />

    <!-- ip, ping -->
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:{1}">
                <Binding Path="Entry.Ip" Mode="OneWay" />
                <Binding Path="Entry.PortHttp" Mode="OneWay" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

    <mui:BbCodeBlock BbCode="{Binding Entry.ErrorsString}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding Entry.RefreshCommand}" Content="{x:Static c:ControlsStrings.Common_TryAgain}" />
</StackPanel>
```

А то у меня тут какие-то чудеса из-за `AddLogicalChild` вкупе с этим самым `DataContext`, даже не представлю, куда копать.

Comment: А что, у вас проблемы с производительностью?

Comment: И откуда у вас взялся `AddLogicalChild`? o_O

Comment: @VladD, со временем копится всякое, интерфейс непростой. Пока ничего сильно напрягающего нет (а то вообще бы избавился от биндингов), но всё равно любопытно, какой подход корректнее.

Comment: @VladD, `AddLogicalChild` использую в своей панели (тут видно одно из её свойств, `mui:Switch.When`), чтобы переключать между контролами по условию. Так по крайней мере в XAML-коде выглядит поизящнее, чем все эти `Visibility={Binding …, Converter=…, ConverterParameter=…}`. Ну и хочется верить, что работает побыстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вопрос вкуса. Разницы в производительности вы, скорее всего, не заметите.

Я обычно стараюсь устанавливать самый «узкий» `DataContext`, как в вашем верхнем примере, чтобы избежать возможных ошибок. Это аналог того принципа, что в функцию стоит (по возможности, конечно) передавать только необходимые параметры.

Comment: Спасибо! Увы, мне не хватает понимания, как работает `Path=<A>.<B>.<C>`, сколько там слушателей, тяжелы ли и оптизируются ли они, но раскопать эту часть WPF я пока не в силах.

Comment: @SurfinBird: По идее, там должно быть по слушателю на каждую компоненту, без этого не обойтись. Но что такое несчастные 100 слушателей по сравнению с одной большой картинкой?